# Rolling standard deviation in r

Tags: r, rolling-computation

I have a dataset of the following type:

```
          PERMNO     date    COMNAM       RET  SHROUT         ME
X20191231  14593 20191231 APPLE INC  0.007307 4443265 1304764723
X20191230  14593 20191230 APPLE INC  0.005935 4443265 1295300568
X20191226  14593 20191226 APPLE INC  0.019840 4443265 1288146956
X20191227  14593 20191227 APPLE INC -0.000379 4443265 1287658153
X20191224  14593 20191224 APPLE INC  0.000951 4443265 1263086897
X20191223  14593 20191223 APPLE INC  0.016318 4443265 1261887260
```

I need to calculate a rolling standard deviation of ret. I tried with

```
roll_sd(df50[,4],252,min=100)
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Error in roll_sd(df50[, 4], 252, min = 100) : 
  adding class "factor" to an invalid object
```

What is this due to? I have checked if there missing values in RET but there are not (`sum(is.na(df50[,4]))` is zero). Unfortunately I cannot give a more detailed example of the data I am using.

Comment: can you try  df50$RET <- as.numeric(df50$RET) and try again?

Comment: @maarvd that won't work. You need to do `df50$RET <- as.numeric(as.character(df50$RET))` otherwise R will convert to integer factor levels.

Comment: @matteo next time, do a dput(df50) than copy the output and paste it, so anyone can have your complete dataframe.

Comment: @AllanCameron that worked perfectly.